# Flatten a JavaScript array -- why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to flatten an array with randomly nested arrays inside. I'm not sure why the function I wrote ends up in an infinite loop:

```
let array = [1, 2, [3]]
var final_array = [] 

function flattener(array){
  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] instanceof Array){
      flattener(array[i])
    }else{
      final_array.push(array[i])
    }
  }
}

flattener(array)
```

What I think SHOULD happen is:

When I'm in the for loop checking for `[3]`, it goes into the if statement, `flattener` gets called again, it resolves, and then I exit the if statement.

Instead, the if statement keeps calling to check `[3]` infinitely, and I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint and running through line by line would've probably shown you what is going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you didn't declare the `i` variable, so it's leaking into the global space and being reset when it recurses.

Change:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
```

To:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
```

Comment: oh my god. THANK YOU SO MUCH I LOVE YOU.

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
/**
 * Flattens an array of arrays into one-dimensional array
 * @param  {Array} arr: the array to be flattened
 * @return {Array}
 */
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flattened, cvalue) {
    return flattened.concat(Array.isArray(cvalue) ? flatten(cvalue) : cvalue);
  }, []); // initial value of flattened array []
}
```

Testing it...

```
let array = [1, 2, [3]]
var falttened = flatten(array)
```

Take a look at his gist: [Array flatten](https://gist.github.com/jherax/7dce66c97ea06150e00c5a6febec26e7)

Answer (score 2):

`Array#concat` plus `Array#map` is *yet another way* you can achieve this

```
var flattener = arr => [].concat.apply([], arr.map(item=>Array.isArray(item) ? flattener(item) : item));
```

or the ES5 version

```
var flattener = function flattener(arr) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function (item) {
    return Array.isArray(item) ? flattener(item) : item;
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

to

```
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```